# The multiplicative constant in the estimate for $S_a(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} d(n)^a$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

Let $a$ be a positive real constant and let $d(n)$ denote the number of divisors of $n.$ Define
$$
S_a(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} d(n)^a.
$$
For $a=1,$ the following is well known 
$$
S_1(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} d(n)=x \log x + (2 \gamma -1) x +{\cal O}(\sqrt{x})
$$
while for more general $a$, one has
$S_a(x) \sim C(a) x (\log x)^{2^a -1}$ where
$$
C(a) = \Gamma(2^a)^{-1} \prod_p \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right)^{2^a} \left( \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{(k+1)^a}{p^k}\right).
$$
I am wondering about accurate estimates of the constant $C(a),$ especially for $a\in (0,1).$

**Edit:** I took @Lucia's suggestion and obtained $C(1/2)\approx 1.14778.$

Here is a plot of the quantity $C(a)$ as a function of $a\in (0,1)$ where three curves are plotted for 100,150 and 200 terms with no appreciable change in the computational result.

[image]

*I am still wondering, however, if analytical lower bounds are known for $C(a)$ where $a\in(0,1),$ or for other larger values of $a.$ In particular, the fact that the maximum is achieved a bit to the right of $a=1/2$ looks intriguing.

Comment: Why don't you just compute $C(a)$ using the product?  100 terms should give you the first couple of digits.

Comment: @Lucia thanks, how do I compute/estimate the sum involving inverse prime powers?

Comment: @AlessandroLanguasco, thanks. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: It converges rapidly (like a geometric progression).  So what's the problem?

Comment: @Lucia, I took your suggestion and the computation rapidly converged. $C(1/2) \approx 1.14778$ was the result. Also tried values of $a$ from $0.05$ to $0.95$ at intervals of $0.05$ and got a unimodal sequence for $C(0.05k)_{k=1}^{19},$ with minimum value $1.02173,$ and maximum value $1.1498,$ with the sampled maximum achieved at $a=0.55$.